# Suppress annoying terminal output junk from PyCharm

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pycharm

I have been using `pycharm-community` for a while now on `Ubuntu` and even if I launch by sending the terminal output to the background

`pycharm-community myfile.py &`

The junk output generated by PyCharm still fills my terminal and I find this really annoying, is there any way to suppress this junk from PyCharm?
And what is the reason why the developers of PyCharm built it this way? I mean to force the junk on users terminal even if they don't want to view it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just redirect your output and error streams to `/dev/null` like you would do for any other command whose output you're not interested in:

```
pycharm-community myfile.py > /dev/null 2>&1
```

As to the following:

> And what is the reason why the developers of pycharm built it this
> way? I mean to force the junk on users terminal even if they don't
> want to view it?

One man's trash is another man's treasure. What you call junk is effectively useful to some people. Maybe the developers assumed that command line users would know how to redirect their output and error streams.

Comment: Thanks, but why does not it stop printing even after I put an '&'. Usually for other applications a simple '&' would throw all the outputs to the background. Don't you think it would make more sense to print these outputs optionally so that we don't have to type these additional characters each time we launch pycharm?

Comment: It still prints to the console because appending `&` launches the command in a forked sub-shell and output will still be sent to the parent. As to whether I think it would make sense to hide the standard output and error streams of an application launched via the command line: no I don't. It's standard Linux/UNIX behavior. Ignore the output, create an `alias` to send it to `/dev/null`, launch your application from the desktop instead of the command-line, ... there are options galore. Of course, you can also always switch back to windows if it bothers you that much.